# How to manage a file upload from a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Activity(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=40)

class File(Model):
    file = FileField(upload_to='files/')
    activity = ForeignKey(Activity)
```

Basically each activity can have 0, 1 or more files.

But now my question is, how can I display the file upload button in my form? And how can I process the uploaded files? Is it done automatically by Django or do I have to manage that manually in the view?

Comment: Do you -really- need File as a separate model?

Comment: No, but since an activity can have multiple files I don't see how I could do without a foreignkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#filefield
After upload in your view somewere in `request.FILES` dict you will have an `UploadedFile` object instance that you can save in your `File` model.

It look's like a hard piece of bread at the beginnig but Django solves file upload very good.
I made several of uploder's for web2print solutions (big files) in Django and im happy about them.